# VS 2017 .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages Project lost ability to Scaffold

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, .net-core-2.2

Any help would be appreciated. Haven't had any luck with Google.

When I put my project together I was able to Scaffold my Courses table and my Sponsors table. However, I can't find the Scaffolding choice anywhere in the project now for a new table "MeetingSchedule".

I've tried right-click "Add > Scaffolding" everywhere and it doesn't exist. I have the SQL server table "MeetingSchedule" viewable in Server Explorer. I have a folder under Pages named "MeetingSchedule".

I have all the Nuget packages installed (I believe), but no luck. No sniff, hint, or partial choice for Scaffolding. It seemed so easy in other projects. It was functioning in this project in the beginning.

**No Choices**

[image: No Scaffolding Choice]

**All my Nuget Packages and Dependecies**

[image: All the Dependencies]

**Previous successful packages some time ago same project**

[image: Previous successful scaffolding]

Comment: Similar question asked 2 days ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/56205382/27989 - Although I don't see a Pages subfolder in your case.

Comment: Similar but my problem had no Scaffold choice at all anywhere. There was no "There are no scaffolders supported for this item" error. It didn't even have the choice for scaffolding that I tried to explain. See 1st screen print ("No Choices"). There is a paging folder, see 3rd screenprint ("previouis successful packages"), there is a Pages folder sitting right there. I fixed my problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a new Razor Pages project in Visual Studio 2017, connect to the same database, and generate Scaffolding hopefully.
The .NET Core was Version 2.1 it said when I picked the template choices(funny, my erroneous project that scaffolding disappeared from was version 2.2). Maybe it was because I installed the 2.2 SDK after. Dunno.

So I was able to Scaffold this single table, and move the items over to my project.
Now something popped up in my project that said "your project is designed to run better on .NET Core 2.2, would you like to update your VS 2017 application?". I clicked ok, upgraded my Visual Studio 2017, and there was Scaffolding again.

All I can assume is something got overwritten with all the update or installs I had to do.